# How would you build this xml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to generate this simple looking XML, looking for a clean way to generate it.

```
<order>
<user>2343></user>
<creditcardtype>2333></creditcarttype>
<country>USA</country>
<orderDetails>
   <amount>23434</amount>
   <shipping>32</shipping>
</orderDetails>
</order>
```

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't collapse things like user id into attributes? ie: `<order user="2343">...`

Comment: If he is calling a non-SOAP webservice he might need a such-formatted XML.

Comment: the format is not in my hands unfort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `XDocument` is taken, here's an `XmlWriter` answer:

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
        xw.WriteStartElement("order");
        xw.WriteElementString("user", "2343");
        xw.WriteElementString("creditcardtype", "2333");
        xw.WriteElementString("country", "USA");
        xw.WriteStartElement("orderDetails");
        xw.WriteElementString("amount", "23434");
        xw.WriteElementString("shipping", "32");
        xw.WriteEndElement();
        xw.WriteEndElement();
    }
    string s = sw.ToString();
```

---

Or with `XmlSerializer`:

```
[XmlRoot("order")] public class Order {
    [XmlElement("user")] public int User { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("creditcardtype")] public int CreditCardType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("country")] public string Country { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("orderDetails")] public OrderDetails Details { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDetails {
    [XmlElement("amount")] public int Amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("shipping")] public int Shipping { get; set; }
}
....
var order = new Order {
    User = 2343, CreditCardType = 2333, Country = "USA",
    Details = new OrderDetails {
        Amount = 23434,
        Shipping = 32
    }
};
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(order.GetType());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ser.Serialize(sw, order);
string s = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the XmlWriter method is the fastest as well, at least it is based on benchmarks that I've done. The WCF DataContractSerializer is quick too, if you want to serialize an object model instead of generating the XML directly.

Comment: +10 to Marc.. Not only for the answer but also taking the effort to explain both the approaches as is.

Answer (score 11):

use XDocument class, so code will be like

```
XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(
    new XElement("order",
        new XElement("user", "2343"),
        new XElement("creditcardtype", "2333"),
        new XElement("country", "USA"),
        new XElement("orderDetails",
            new XElement ("amount", "23434"),
            new XElement ("shipping", "32")

        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

see [LINQ to XMl](http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2008/02/18/linq-to-xml-creating-complex-xml-through-linq.aspx) way to do that, something like this

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("order",
                   new XElement("user", "2343"),
                   new XElement("creditcardtype", "2333"),
                   new XElement("country", "USA"),
               new XElement("orderDetails",
                   new XElement("amount", "23434"),
                   new XElement("shipping", "32"))));
doc.Save("myxml.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

XmlElement order = xml.CreateElement("order");

xml.AppendChild(order);

XmlElement user = xml.CreateElement("user");
user.InnerText = "2343";
order.AppendChild(user);

XmlElement ccType = xml.CreateElement("creditcardtype");
ccType.InnerText = "2333";
order.AppendChild(ccType);
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

1. Write an XML schema describing your structure. (You could also use `xsd.exe` to automatically generate the schema according to a given XML file.)
2. Use `xsd.exe /classes` to genereate C# classes according to your XML schema.
3. Now you can use the `XmlSerializer` class to serialize/deserialize your XML from/to a C# object-structure.

There is also a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/Serialization.aspx) describing this approach.

Comment: This is also about the slowest method of all the ones mentioned.

Comment: I guess the XmlDocument approach is even slower... Anyway, what i like about it is that everything is strongly typed and you could even do a schema validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the Linq to XML suggestions, but for completeness I just have to add this one:

```
var xe = XElement.Parse("<order><user>2343</user><creditcardtype>2333</creditcarttype><country>USA</country><orderDetails><amount>23434</amount><shipping>32</shipping></orderDetails></order>");
```

:)