# mvc 2 help with xml partials

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-2, partials

Ok, so in order to provide Data to Fusion Charts I need to give it some XML..
I have narrowed it down to this

```
myChart.setDataXML("<%Html.RenderPartial("Graph", Model.graph_data); %>");
```

which renders

```
myChart.setDataXML("
    <chart caption='Grafico' xAxisName='Factores' yAxisName='Porcentaje' decimals='0' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix='%25' yAxisMinValue='0' yAxisMaxValue='100' bgColor='FFFFFF' showBorder='1' bgSWF='/Content/images/LogoGraficas.png' slantLabels='1' labelDisplay='Rotate' baseFontColor='333333'>

<set value='100' label='Pierna' />
        <styles>
            <definition>
                <style name='myShadow' type='Shadow' color='999999' angle='45'/>
            </definition>
            <application>
                <apply toObject='DataValues' styles='myShadow' />
            </application>
        </styles>
    </chart>");
```

But what I need rendered is..

```
myChart.setDataXML("<chart caption='Grafico' xAxisName='Factores' yAxisName='Porcentaje' decimals='0' formatNumberScale='0' numberSuffix='%25' yAxisMinValue='0' yAxisMaxValue='100' bgColor='FFFFFF' showBorder='1' bgSWF='/Content/images/LogoGraficas.png' slantLabels='1' labelDisplay='Rotate' baseFontColor='333333'><set value='100' label='Pierna' /><styles><definition><style name='myShadow' type='Shadow' color='999999' angle='45'/></definition><application><apply toObject='DataValues' styles='myShadow' /></application></styles></chart>");
```

How can I make the RenderPartial give me back the string without the spaces?

Comment: Can you re-edit the 3rd code block please so that it's indented?

Comment: But that's the point, it needs to be like that otherwise it returns a javascript error... the third block works fine.. the first block gives me javascript error... they are not different except the spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [convert the PartialView output to a string](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/) and then manipulate it as u wish.

So what you will end up doing is something like this.

```
string data = RenderPartialToString("~/..../..../..../Graph.ascx", Model.graph_data);
data.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
myChart.setDataXML(data);
```

I know it's not the best solution but it might fix your problem.

**Update :**

Better Ways to generate your XML is to use : `XmlWriter` or `XmlSerializer` or `XDocument`

I'm not an XML Expert so i don't know which is best for your case but i like the way the `XmlSerializer` works.

See some examples [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789764/how-would-you-build-this-xml-in-c)